# Create group communicator in mpi (mpi4py)

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to create an MPI group using *mpi4py*. My current attempt looks like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
newGroup = comm.group.Excl([0, 1, 2])
print newGroup.size

newComm = comm.Create_group(newGroup)
print newComm
print newComm.Get_size()
```

The `newGroup.size` call does return 2 (I started the application with 5 processes) and the `newComm` variable indicates to be a communicator. But as soon as I try to call `Get_size` an exception is thrown:

*mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator*

How can I create a new communicator based on a predefined sequence of process IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newComm` is a legit communicator on tasks `[3-4]`, but is `MPI_COMM_NULL` on tasks `[0-2]`. The standard does not allow you to invoke `MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_NULL, ...)`, and hence your error.

The solution is to call `newComm.Get_size()` explicitly on tasks `[3-4]`, or on any tasks where `newComm` is **not** `MPI_COMM_NULL`.